# Security Risks of having an API for registering a new user

Tags: api, security

I have this question in mind and I wanted to get other developer's opinion on this issue.

For creating a user (like in Facebook or creating an account in Gmail), some people suggested to have an public/private (means we don't tell developers how to use it) action in API for it. I, however, think it is a security risk as even if it is not documented, a hacker can simple see the calls and http requests when our front-end app is using that api action to create a new user (using a web debugger like fiddler) and can find the url to that action so simple ! like this POST ~/api/user/create
and then he/she can send thousands of requests to create user, users needs to be verified but still he/she is adding a lot of junk users in our database and puts a lot of pressure on our servers.

So the question is how do we handle this? Allow this only on our website or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use CAPTCHA to verify that's a real user.